# How to compute expectations from a probability density function?

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, density-function

How to find a tax/subsidy in an income probability density function situation?

I am asked the following question:

> Suppose all families with $Y \lt 20$ are given transfer payments equal to $(20-Y)/2$;
>       and suppose the cost of these transfers is raised by taxing all families
>       with $Y \gt 20$ an amount $t(Y-20).$
>
> Solve for $t.$

I am trying to understand how to develop an equation to solve for $t,$ but none of my answers work.

The probability density function is triangular:

[image: income probability density function]

---

The values I have solved for are:

- **Height** :  1/30
- **Mean**   :  26.67
- **Median** :  25.36
- **slope of $Y\gt 20$**    : 1/600
- **slope of $20\lt Y\lt 60$**  : 1/1200

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So ummm what is the question?  Find t such that ... what?  That the amount raised = amount spent? Or find t to maximise something subject to a budget constraint? Or something else?

Comment: Have you noted the nice symmetry of this distribution?  Because the height at $20-y$ is the same as the height at $20 + 2y$ for $0 \le y \le 20,$ then for small $dy$ the number of families with incomes between $20-y$ and $20-(y+dy)$ for $0\lt y\le 20$ is one-half the number of families with incomes between $20 + 2y$ and $20 + 2y + 2 dy.$  Thus the contribution from each of the latter families, which is proportional to $2 y t,$ must exactly balance the transfer to the former families, who receive an amount proportional to $y/2.$  That makes it obvious what $t$ should be.